# Scheme streams and circular lists

Tags: list, functional-programming, lisp, scheme, circular-list

In Scheme/Lisp I am trying to make a function that converts a list into a circular list. Therefore, I believe I need to construct an infinite stream in which the tail of the list points to the head of the list.

Here is my code so far:

```
(define (rotate-list l1 l1copy)
  (if (null? (force (cdr l1)))
      (cons (car l1) (delay l1copy)))
      (cons (car l1) (delay (rotate-list (force (cdr l1)) l1copy))))
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need streams to make a circular list.

There are two approaches to creating circular lists, the standard Scheme approach, and the Racket approach (since Racket's conses are immutable). I will look at examples using [SRFI 1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html)'s `circular-list` function. Here's the reference implementation:

```
(define (circular-list val1 . vals)
  (let ((ans (cons val1 vals)))
    (set-cdr! (last-pair ans) ans)
    ans))
```

What that does is to find the last pair in the list of given values, and `set-cdr!`s it back to the beginning of that list. Pretty straightforward, right?

In Racket, conses are immutable, so `set-cdr!` does not exist. So instead, Racket does it this way:

```
(define (circular-list val1 . vals)
  (let ([ph (make-placeholder #f)])
    (placeholder-set! ph
      (cons val1 (let loop ([vals vals])
                   (if (null? vals)
                     ph
                     (cons (car vals) (loop (cdr vals)))))))
    (make-reader-graph ph)))
```

This uses Racket's [`make-reader-graph`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._make-reader-graph%29%29) function to handle the cycles. Very nifty. :-)

Comment: Could you give an example of creating a literal cyclic list in Racket, please?  The [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/reader.html#(part._parse-graph)) mentions something like `#0=(1 . #0#)`, but the REPL does not accept this expression.