# Converting a list to a circular list in Chicken scheme?

Tags: scheme, circular-list, chicken-scheme

In trying to find how to convert such a list, I came across
[Scheme streams and circular lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678943/scheme-streams-and-circular-lists). However, that answer requires features in Racket not available in Chicken scheme. Can Anyone point Me in the direction of how to do this in Chicken scheme instead? Or in a scheme-variant-neutral fashion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can mutate the list, here's a standard way:

```
(define (make-circular lst)
  ; helper for finding the last pair in a list
  (define (last-pair lst)
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        lst
        (last-pair (cdr lst))))
        ; special case: if the list is empty
  (cond ((null? lst) '())
        (else
         ; set the last pair to point to the head of the list
         (set-cdr! (last-pair lst) lst)
         lst)))
```

Be aware that the above will modify the input list. Other than that, it works as expected:

```
(make-circular '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> #0=(1 2 3 4 5 . #0#)

(car (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (cdr (make-circular '(1 2 3 4 5))))))))
=> 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple when you use SRFIs:

(use srfi-1)
(define l '(1 2 3 4))
(apply circular-list l)